# How to carry out a functionality change in the application without code changes and only database changes?

Tags: java, database

I have been asked in an interview about this question of how to carry out a functionality change in the application without code changes and only database changes? For example

The application is a student course registration where the condition is that the system administrator provides capability of applying to only a single course out of different courses.

The application system should be supportable to the system administrator such that in the future the student can apply for multiple courses.

The application should be flexible to the admin to directly change at the DB end without affecting the functionality and how to do it.

I scratched my head but I did not got conclusion as I don't have deep knowledge about the DB.

Comment: I think you need to rephrase the question as I didnt get what is the current functionality of  system and what is the new functionality that should be achived by just changing the database. if you can type it as the system currently do this .... and after changing the db it should do this ....

Comment: The application is a student course registration where the condition is that the system administrator provides capability of applying to only a single course out of different courses.

The application system should be supportable to the system administrator such that in the future the student can apply for multiple courses.

Answer (score 0):

For such requirement, developer can keep both functionality in codebase which will be enabled or disabled by flag which should be maintained in database. 
With this approach you can manage the enable/disable the feature without changing the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of database triggers/procedures that would define the rules for inserts and updates.

For example, you could create a trigger that would run before inserting in to the student_to_course join table (with columns like "student_id", "course_id") that would check that this student id doesn't already exist in the table. This would limit the student to a single course.

This way, the DB could throw an error when attempting to insert another student-course relationship. If the application has enough error handling, it would be able to handle this.

By changing the trigger later on, you could allow for students to apply to multiple courses.